# I have problem in creating joint left and right triangle together that shape in some sort of box

Tags: php

I want to create this:

```
12345
12341
12312
12123
11234
```

Above should be the output. My code is:

```
<?php
for ($i=5; $i >=1 ; $i--) { 
    for ($j=1; $j <=$i ; $j++) { 
        echo $j."&nbsp";
    }
    echo "<br>";
        }

    for ($y=1; $y <=4 ; $y++) { 
        for ($z=1; $z <=$y ; $z++) { 
            echo $z."&nbsp";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

It displays output like:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
1
12
123
1234
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. The pattern says: for each row, iterate up to `n - i` with numbers `1..` and then iterate to `i` starting again from `1..`. Your code prints the first bit correctly, but it's adding a line break before writing the second part.

```
<?php
$n = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $n - $i; $j++) { 
        echo $j;
    }

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) { 
        echo $j;
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
12345
12341
12312
12123
11234
```